# Does the post office at Budapest airport accept credit cards?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, budapest

I'm planning to buy some public transport tickets at the [post office](http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/shopping_and_gastronomy/services/post-office-8186.html) at the airport; and I am wondering if they accept **credit cards** or just debit cards and cash.

Also, will they take Euros?

Comment: Why not book the Budapest card online(can book in euros or HUF) and collect it at the airport ?

Comment: @DumbCode I cannot, because the credit card that I have right now is not allowed to be used in Hungary (I'm in the process of getting another one specifically for this trip).

Answer (score 4):

If the post office doesn't accept credit cards, you can buy public transport tickets at [BKK](http://bkk.hu) customer service points. You will probably see one right in front of you once you leave the baggage claim area. They are very visible. They do accept credit cards. Not sure about EUR though.

Answer (score 3):

There are machines in the bus stop, those take credit cards.

[image]